# My input is not turning into an integer even though I want it to

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
def add(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 + num2
    print(ans)

def subtract(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 - num2 
    print(ans)

def multiply(num1, num2):
    ans = num1 * num2
    print(ans)

def divide (num1, num2):
    if num2 == 0:
        print("Hey, you can't do that man")
    else:
        ans = num1 / num2
    print(ans)




while True:
    option = input("What would you like to do? Add (1), Subtract (2), Multiply (3), Divide (4). Choose the corresponding number for your option. ")
    if option == "1":
        num1 = int(input("What is the first number? "))
        num2 = int(input("What is the second number? "))
        add(num1, num2)
      
    elif option == "2": 
        num1 = int(input("What is the first number? "))
        num2 = int(input("What is the second number? "))
        subtract(num1, num2)
        
    elif option == "3":
        num1 = input("What is the first number? ")
        num2 = input("What is the second number? ")
        multiply(num1, num2)

    elif option == "4":
        num1 = int(input("What is the first number? "))
        num2 = int(input("What is the second number? "))
        divide(num1, num2)

    print("Error, option not valid.")
    print()
```

I ran this in Replit and it worked fine but for VS Code it is not working. What is the issue here?

Comment: Your "option 3" handler is missing the `int(...)` wrappers.  Everything works except multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like in your third option, the one for multiplication, you forgot to write "int" before your input.

Here's the fix:

```py
elif option == "3":
    num1 = int(input("What is the first number? "))
    num2 = int(input("What is the second number? "))
    multiply(num1, num2)
```

I would also recommend having the "option not valid" text displayed only when the user inputs a number not listed. For example:

```py
def add(num1, num2): 
    ans = num1 + num2 
    print(ans)

def subtract(num1, num2): 
    ans = num1 - num2 
    print(ans)

def multiply(num1, num2): 
    ans = num1 * num2 
    print(ans)

def divide (num1, num2): 
    if num2 == 0: 
        print("Hey, you can't do that man") 
    else: 
        ans = num1 / num2 
        print(ans)

while True: 

    option = input("What would you like to do? Add (1), Subtract (2), Multiply (3), Divide (4). Choose the corresponding number for your option. ") 
    if option == "1": 
        num1 = int(input("What is the first number? ")) 
        num2 = int(input("What is the second number? ")) 
        add(num1, num2)

    elif option == "2": 
        num1 = int(input("What is the first number? "))
        num2 = int(input("What is the second number? "))
        subtract(num1, num2)

    elif option == "3":
        num1 = int(input("What is the first number? "))
        num2 = int(input("What is the second number? "))
        multiply(num1, num2)

    elif option == "4":
        num1 = int(input("What is the first number? "))
        num2 = int(input("What is the second number? "))
        divide(num1, num2)

    else:
        print("Error, option not valid.\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to putting int() wrappers around option 3 I would suggest to move the error message inside the loop to avoid repeated printing.Otherwise, it works fine in VS Code.

```
 elif option == "4":
     num1 = int(input("What is the first number? "))
     num2 = int(input("What is the second number? "))
     divide(num1, num2)

 else:
     print("Error, option not valid.")
 print()
```